# For which primes $p$ and integers $n$ is every $p$-Sylow subgroup of $S_n$ commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

This question has been asked before, and a partial solution was given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116736/prove-that-every-sylow-p-subgroup-of-s-n-is-abelian-if-and-only-if-np2). I figured I would post a new question as the other is several months old. If this is StackExchange faux-pas, I apologize.

I was able to follow the posted solution to show that for a fixed prime $p$, if $n < p^2$, then every $p$-Sylow subgroup of $S_n$ is Abelian.

However, I'm struggling to understand the counterexample for the case $n \geq p^2$. If someone could expound upon the given answer, or perhaps give a new one, that would be much appreciated.

Continuing the notation in the already posted answer, $Q_p$ will be a group of order $p^p$, which will be contained in the $p$-Sylow subgroup. I'm struggling to find an element which doesn't commute, though - since $Q_p$ is a product of disjoint cycles, won't all elements commute?

Comment: You just need to show that any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{p^2}$ is non-Abelian, and you can do that just by writing down two non-commuting elements.

Comment: Right. My problem is finding two such elements.

Comment: For $p=3$, you could take the two non-commuting elements to be $(1,2,3)$  and $(1,4,7)(2,5,8)(3,6,9)$. You can generalize that to other primes.